# https redirection via .htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel, mod-rewrite, https

i am using `apache` and `laravel` and want to redirect all my requests to `https`.
For Example:
I want this url

> abc.com/my/test

to be redirected to

> https://abc.123/my/test

Currently i have below code in the file

> /var/www/html/laravelProjet/public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# For redirecting HTTP to HTTPS
# comment & un-comment below lines according to certificates
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} 

</IfModule>
```

**Issue:** The `adobe htaccess` settings does the redirect but to wrong path. It redirects to

> "https://abc.123/index.php"

and i want it to be redirected to the link mentioned above.

Comment: Then do the https redirect before the internal path mapping.

Comment: The [L] flag on "Handle Front Controller" means it should stop processing rules if this one matched

Comment: Removing the [L] Flag worked. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The [L] flag causes mod_rewrite to stop processing the rule set. In
>   most contexts, this means that if the rule matches, no further rules
>   will be processed.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

You could try removing the `[L]` flag on the line:

`RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`

You can also redirect to HTTPS with PHP:

```
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") {
    $url = "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header("Location: $url");
    exit;
}
```